# Algorithm to find optimal timetable

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

I am searching a algorithm or general a way to solve the following problem:

Students A,...,M are inscribed for the written examniations of various modules. The inscriptions are given in the following table. If each student can do one exam per day, how many days are necessary, at minimum, for organizing the session?

```
          |A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|
Module 1  | | | |X| |X|X| |X|X| | | |
Module 2  |X| | | | |X| | | |X|X| | |
Module 3  | |X| | | | | |X| | |X| |X|
Module 4  |X| | |X| | | | | | | | | |
Module 5  | | |X| |X| | | | |X| | |X|
Module 6  | | |X| | | | |X| | | | | |
Module 7  |X|X| | | | | | |X| |X| | |
Module 8  | | |X| | | |X| | | | |X| |
```

How an I solve the problem?

Comment: I would say the first step is to build a table of compatibility, i.e. a table that tells you if it is possible to have module x and module y the same day.

Comment: I would suggest looking into Critical Path Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With graph colouring.

Make a node for each module, and whenever a student has modules i and j then there is an edge between nodes i and j. Colour the graph, the colours represent days. There is an edge between nodes whenever the modules cannot be on the same day, so the colouring gives a valid schedule. A minimum colouring gives the shortest schedule.

As a suggestion for actually solving the instance (ie, an algorithm for graph colouring), for this size I would take a simple fairly brute force approach, sort of like this:

```
for k in 1 ..
    tryColour(k, 1)

tryColour(k, i):
    if i > numnodes:
        found it
    for c in 1 .. k:
        if node i can have colour c:
            colours[i] = c
            tryColour(k, i+1)
```

I paid no attention to detail there, it's just for the idea: pick a node, give it a colour that is not immediately impossible, then recursively colour the rest. If the recursive colouring comes up empty, try again with the next colour. Do this whole thing with an increasing number of colours until you find a solution.

Comment: Thank you. With this, I could solve the problem "by hand". But when I have built the Graph, is there a algorithm to calculate the minimum needed numbers of colors?

Comment: If you're using java you can add a state to your nodes, and simply count them or use any other mechanism.

Comment: @Jelle how does that give a colouring though?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a table of incompatibility, which should look like:

```
a[1] = [2,4,5,7,8]
a[2] = [1,3,4,5,7]
a[3] = [2,3,5,6,7]
a[4] = [1,2,7,8]
a[5] = [1,2,3,6,8]
a[6] = [3,5,8]
a[7] = [1,2,3,4]
a[8] = [1,5,6]
```

I think it is something in the idea of:

- Create a day-node, put a module in it with its incompatible modules.
- Then, as long as any given node still has incompatible modules not resolved:

  - pop an incompatible module from that node,
  - either place it in a node that is compatible, or create a new day-node
  - then remove that module from any other day node in which it was still present

Each day-node has a list of modules that will happen that day, and a list of modules that cannot happen that day. I am not entirely sure how to prove it is optimal, though. It seems to, because it considers the incompatibilities with the modules that have been seen first.

An example of quick and dirty python implementation: https://repl.it/BY2B